# What is the Euler characteristic of the edge word $ abc^{-1}b^{-1}da^{-1}d^{-1} c $?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces

> Identify the Euler characteristic of the edge word 
>   $ abc^{-1}b^{-1}da^{-1}d^{-1} c $.

The Euler characteristic is 
$$ X=V-E+F$$
where $V$, $E$ and $F$ are the vertices, edges and faces respectively.

The solution to the problem is given below.

**I do not understand how to find the number of vertices from the polygon model or edge word[image]l.**

Comment: [Please look at how I've edited your post](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3b148203-ddc1-4e13-b909-f75eb23e40c5/view-source). [You can go here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to find the number of vertices for this edge word.

We begin with $8$ distinct vertices. Identifying the two edges labeled $a$ eliminates $2$ vertices (since two vertex pairs are glued together). Then the identification of the two edges labeled $d$ identifies these two vertices (look at the $a$ edge in the lower right), so we subtract $1$ again.

The two vertices at the $c$ edge in the upper right have already been identified, so gluing the two $c$ edges eliminates $2$ more vertices. Finally, we see in the same way that gluing the $b$ edges eliminates $2$ more.

In this way, we see that all $7$ vertices not equal to the one in the lower right, where $a$ and $d$ meet, are identified to this vertex. So all vertices, after identification, become one vertex.