# Classification of a surface from edge words

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

Let $X$ the quotient of an octagon by the edgeword $aba^{-1}bcdc^{-1}d^{-1}$. Justify that $X$ is homeomorphic to a connected sum of 4 copies of a certain compact surface $Y$.

I believe that from the Classification Theorem, this space $Y$ must be either a Torus or the Projective Plane (my intuition goes for the projective plane) but how do I proceed to "cut" this word into 4 projective planes ?

Comment: Since it has $b\dots b$ and not $b\dots b^{-1}$, it must be nonorientable, so projective planes and not toruses. The usual algorithm for working out the exact answer goes by working out the number of vertices and the number of edges, using those to get the Euler characteristic, using that to get the genus, and then using properties of the genus of a connected sum to complete the calculation. I bet this has been done many times on this website for many different surfaces; why not do a search, instead of cluttering up the site with one more example?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I haven't learnt about Euler's characteristic nor I believe I was supposed to use it here, my teacher probably put this question on my list with  the procedure of "cutting and glueing" in mind, hence having asked "how do I procedure to "cut" this word into 4 projective planes"

Comment: As Gerry Myerson said : look for similar questions like this one : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3583221/305862 or this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/406175/305862 obtained by plugging your edgeword into the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: What you are supposed to do is to understand the proof (I assume that it is in the textbook you are using) of the classification theorem for surfaces (which is algorithmic) and follow this algorithm in the case of this particular word.